# How can JSON key change with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, key

I get back the data from DB with php, and I get it back as follows so I want to modify it.

This what I tried:

```
$result = $db->run("SELECT * FROM.....")->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $key => $val) {

    $result[$key] = $result[$key]['id'];

}
```

I want to change the key ( 0, 1) to the id values (5, 6) Change this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 5,
    "date_created": "2021-08-18 03:35:31",
    "status": 1
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 6,
    "date_created": "2021-08-18 03:35:55",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "5": {
    "id": 5,
    "date_created": "2021-08-18 03:35:31",
    "status": 1
  },
  "6": {
    "id": 6,
    "date_created": "2021-08-18 03:35:55",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose

$result = $db->run("SELECT * FROM.....")->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $key => $val) {

$result[$key] = $result[$key]['id'];
}

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$newResult = [];
foreach($result as $key => $val) {
    $newResult[$val['id']] = $val;
}

print_r($newResult);
```